# Which flows does Room for android use internally? Is it cold or hot?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-flow

When you make a query using Room, you can specify the method to return Flow<T>.
It doesn't make any requests until it have a collector, but if you are already subscribed, inserting new data will update the flow.
Is it cold or hot? What is under the hood?

If, for instance, I do this:

```kotlin
query().buffer().filter {
    api.makeLongFilteringRequest(it)
}.collect {
    ui.show(it)
}
```

Will it execute sequentially (like a hot flow) or concurrently (like a cold flow)?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by sequential/concurrent in this case? Both hot and cold flows are always sequential, meaning we collect one item at a time and in the order of emitting. Majority of existing operators are also fully sequential. Using `buffer()` we can process multiple steps concurrently, but each of them is still sequential and the whole pipeline still behaves pretty much sequentially. It feels a little like [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). think it would be easier to discuss your real case and explain your concerns about it.

Comment: I misunderstood how buffer() works. Thought this would work differently on a cold flow.

Is this still considered a cold flow?
`val hotFlow = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()
fun coldFlow() = flow {
    doSomethingAndEmit()
    hotFlow.collect { emit(it) }
}
emitValuesToHotFlow()
`

Comment: `coldFlow()` still returns a cold flow, because calling this function doesn't do anything by its own. Only when we start collecting the flow, it will subscribe to the hot flow and start collecting it. I still feel you focus too much on the hot/flow distinction - instead of your real problem.

Comment: Every flow “operator” function (the nonterminal ones) returns a new cold flow whose behavior under the hood is that each time they are collected, they begin collecting from their parent flow and then do something with those results to achieve whatever emission behavior they are supposed to do. So the upstream flow can be hot or cold, but the returned downstream flow is always cold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source flow from Room is cold because it doesn’t do anything unless collected, and you can collect it multiple times in parallel or sequentially. Each and every time you collect a flow from Room, it queries and emits the current value in the database and also sets up an internal listener that will repeat the query and emit that result. These listeners are invoked every time a change is made to the database. When a collect call is terminated, the listener is destroyed.

Calling buffer or filter on a hot flow (SharedFlow or StateFlow) returns a cold flow that only does the operations on the parent hot flow when they are collected. The hot flow behavior itself is unaffected. It sees collection of the downstream flows just like any other collector and doesn’t know they are doing additional operations on what they collect from it.  So as far as your question is concerned, it is irrelevant whether Room returns a hot or cold flow.

The phrasing of your last sentence suggests a misunderstanding of the terms hot and cold. Cold flows are usually sequential unless buffered in which case they have intermediate parallelism. And hot flows can’t really be thought of in terms of sequential vs. buffered because they just keep emitting whether or not collectors are ready or not.

Comment: It it possible that Room has some optimization under the hood where when a flow has multiple collectors, it uses a shared listener for all of them so redundant queries are not made.  Not exactly the same as a hot flow but the behavior would be quite similar to a SharedFlow with `replay = 1`.

Answer (score -2):

it is a hot flow. You should be collecting the output of filter